# writing a java method that returns a boolean from a search

Tags: java, recursion

I have written a method that searches a tree to test if any integers are negative.

But I am struggling to get the right Boolean value returned.  Any pointers as to where I am going wrong?

What I want to achieve is that as soon as the condition statement is met a false is returned but unfortunately my code is always returning a true

```
static boolean allE(Tree<Integer> x) {
  if (x.isEmpty()) return true;
  else {
    if (x.getValue()%2 != 0) return false;  
  }

  allE(x.getLeft());
  allE(x.getRight());

  return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to consider the return value of `allE(x.getLeft())` and `allE(x.getRight())`. Clearly if either of those returns `false` then the function should return `false`.

Comment: Even though you call `allE` recursivly, you don´t use its return-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to evaluate the return-value of the recursive calls:

```
static boolean allE(Tree<Integer> x)
{
    if (x.isEmpty())
        return true;
    else {
        if (x.getValue()%2 != 0) return false;    
    }
    if(!allE(x.getLeft()) || !allE(x.getRight())) 
        return false;
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

When you recurse on `allE` you need to consider the result of that recursion. Easiest fix I see, change

```
allE(x.getLeft());
allE(x.getRight());
return true;
```

to

```
return allE(x.getLeft()) && allE(x.getRight());
```

Although, I think it makes more sense to write the algorithm such that you recurse on even explicitly. And `allE` saves three letters compared to `allEven` (**please** use meaningful names for methods and variables). Something like,

```
static boolean allEven(Tree<Integer> node) {
    if (node.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    } else if (node.getValue() % 2 == 0) {
        return allEven(node.getLeft()) && allEven(node.getRight());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the results of your recursive tests properly.
It should be:

```java
if (x.isEmpty()) {
    return true;
}
boolean thisNodeEven = x.getValue() % 2 == 0;
return thisNodeEven && allE(x.getLeft()) && allE(x.getRight());
```